# Show formatted HTML line as popup?

Tags: html, abap

I am having a one single row with text with HTML-tags. Example.

```
    html_string = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> <h1> My First Heading</h1> <p> My first paragraph.</p> </body> </html> '.
```

I want to give the value of html_string back as a formatted HTML text like that:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Best would be in a popup. Anyone got any idea? Best would be a function module or so. I've been looking around for some while but I have not found anything which fits my requirements.

Comment: Is it to be rendered via SAP GUI for Windows?

Comment: yes it is! If I look it up via Debugger and select "HTML-Browser" it looks just as i need it but i couldn't find anything like i described above.

Answer (score 3):

I just found exactly what I needed. This might help any future programmers:

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/de-DE/abenstring_function_escape_abexa.htm

```
REPORT  demo_escape_html.

CLASS demo DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS demo IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA: body     TYPE string,
          esc_body TYPE string.

    body = `<table border> `
        && `<tr><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr> `
        && `<tr><td>21</td><td>22</td></tr> `
        && `</table>`.

    esc_body = escape( val    = body
                       format = cl_abap_format=>e_html_text ).

    cl_demo_output=>new(
      )->begin_section( 'Original text'
      )->write_text( body

      )->next_section( 'Original text formatted as HTML'
      )->write_html( body

      )->next_section( 'Escaped text'
      )->write_text( esc_body

      )->next_section( 'Escaped text formatted as HTML'
      )->write_html( esc_body

      )->display( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  demo=>main( ).
```

Comment: `cl_demo_*` classes are only for test purpose, you should not use this class productively. Instead, use `cl_abap_browser`.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML is XHTML (XML-compatible), then you may display it like any other XML, and the integrated Windows browser will automatically indent the XML levels:

```
DATA l_xml TYPE string.
cl_abap_browser=>show_xml( xml_string = l_xml title = 'text' ).
```

If the HTML is not XHTML, there's no SAP program which interprets "begin-end" tags (like `<br>`, `<li>`, etc.)